# How do I discover who's still connecting to Salesforce using TLS 1.0?

Tags: tls

I recently got the standard warning email from SF saying that the prod instances will turn off TLS 1.0 next year, and they've detected some of our connections are still using it. Is there any way I can discover clues as to which users and/or client applications might be connecting using TLS 1.0 ?

Comment: You can download the login records.

Comment: Setup > Users > Login History > Download

Answer (score 5):

I like to query the LoginHistory object to get this information.

```
SELECT Id, TlsProtocol, UserId, Format(LoginTIme), SourceIp, ApiType, ApiVersion, Application, Browser, CipherSuite, ClientVersion, LoginType, LoginUrl, Platform 
FROM LoginHistory 
WHERE LoginTIme = THIS_YEAR AND TlsProtocol = 'TLS 1.0'
```

Note that I have specified LoginTime to be This Year in order to reduce the amount of records that are returned.  Also you can't use relationships to get the User's name.  You'll have to make a separate query for that.

---

Per @SimonLawrence's comment:  Note: THIS_YEAR is calendar driven though, so right now that would need a user to have logged in over just the last 5 days.. I would maybe broaden that incase you have integrations etc. that only log in monthly or so on. LAST_180_DAYS might be a reasonable one (depending on how many result rows you get I suppose!)

Comment: That is a bad ass solution. Note: THIS_YEAR is calendar driven though, so right now that would need a user to have logged in over just the last 5 days.. I would maybe broaden that incase you have integrations etc. that only log in monthly or so on. LAST_180_DAYS might be a reasonable one (depending on how many result rows you get I suppose!)

Comment: @SimonLawrence I was hoping that was implicit, but I've now made it explicit.  Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily report on users who are still using TLS 1.0 from login history.

[image]